# Parsing JSON data received in blogger api response

Tags: json, api, blogger

I have completed a GET request and have the info I need.  I just need help parsing this onto my site.

Any help would be really appreciated as I've been on this for about 3 days now :(

I have used the following to GET my blog posts from blogger:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET","https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/1731759086281795196/
posts/?key=[MY API KEY HERE]", false);

xhr.send();
```

The console is showing this request is successful.

```
status = 20
statustext = OK
```

Now I need to take the "title", "content" & "published" date (as shown in the JSON response) and parse this onto my site.

Any ideas of how this is done?  This is probably for someone that has worked with the Blogger API or similar blog API's in the past.

Comment: You would use a JSON parser kit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abandoned question up using simplexml_load_file to load the publc feed.